# how to replace these simple if else PHP statements with a function?

Tags: php, if-statement, optimization

How can i improve or replace these if else PHP statements to a function which can take on a file name variable for ( eg images/dogtypeX.jpg ) instead of hard-coding every single dog type? Thank you to your all PHP masters!

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
$dogtype = $_GET["dogtype"];
$dogname = $_GET["dogname"];

if($dogtype== "dogtype1")
{ $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/dogtype1.jpg');}
else if ($dogtype== "dogtype2")
{ $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/dogtype2.jpg');}
else if ($dogtype=="dogtype3") 
{ $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/dogtype3.jpg');}
else if ($dogtype=="dogtype4")
{ $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/dogtype4.jpg');}
else if ($dogtype=="dogtype5")
{ $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/dogtype5.jpg');}
imagettftext($jpg_image, $dogtype, $dogname);
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it seems that you can do something very simple like :

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
$dogtype = $_GET["dogtype"];
$dogname = $_GET["dogname"];
supported_dogtypes = array("dogtype1", "dogtype2", "dogtype3"); // ...
if(in_array($dogtype, supported_dogtypes){
    $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/$dogtype.jpg");
    imagettftext($jpg_image, $dogtype, $dogname);
    imagejpeg($jpg_image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass file name in a function.

```
function dogType($dogtype){
   $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/$dogtype.jpg");
// DO your other stuf..
}

//function call
$dogtype = $_GET["dogtype"];
dogType($dogtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the number of the "dogtype" using preg_match, then automatically assign which image should be created based on that.

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
$dogtype = $_GET["dogtype"];
$dogname = $_GET["dogname"];

$dog_type_number = preg_match('/\d+/', $dogtype, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$dog_type_image = 'dogtype' . $matches[0][0];

$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/$dog_type_image.jpg");
imagettftext($jpg_image, $dogtype, $dogname);
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
```

For example, if the image name is "dogtype124" preg_match will find only the digits i.e. "124" then automatically attach them on the end.

Comment: @Rookie PHP Can you accept the answer if you end up using my code? Thanks